# Absolutely positioned images in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, position

My client's websit has a navigation bar in the form of a wide image banner. I'm using the HTML `<area>` tag and JavaScript to overlay navigation buttons (which are themselves images) whenever the user mouses over certain regions of the banner. The buttons are absolutely positioned over their respective `<area>`'s, and are hidden/shown based on the mouse position.

While I have it working on Chrome, I've noticed that the buttons are appearing in the wrong place on Safari. I've struggled to figure out what the issue is, but haven't been successful so far. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

Here's a link to the draft of the site: http://bit.ly/dLIh4k. Thanks!

Comment: the link you provided is password protected.

Comment: If we could see the site, I'm certain there's an easier way.  Absolutely positioned images overlayed with javascript is getting to be pretty old practice these days.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this applies to you but there are known issues with absolute positioning if the parent uses relative positioning.