# Webkit Browsers position absolutely sometimes

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, position

I have a website that I've tested in all other major browsers that works fine. My problem is on WebKit browsers (Safari 5.1.4 and Chrome 21) where my asolutely positioned text works some of the time. If I refresh 10 times, it gets positioned correctly probably twice. The funny thing is, if I zoom in on the browser, the formatting gets fixed.

Website is: http://survey-snap.com/ssContact/
The elements are bulletpoints in the blue section.

CSS:

```
.bulletpoints {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 1.11em;
}

.bulletpoints li {
    height: 56px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.bulletpoints img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.bulletpoints span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}

.bulletpoints p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 61px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Absolutely positioned images in Chrome/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791779/absolutely-positioned-images-in-chrome-safari?rq=1), I just re-wrote that section to remove the positioning and just floated it instead.